# bulk updating mysql specific column with a calculation

Tags: mysql

I have about 2000 different lines in my database MYSQL in the table `catalog_product_flat_2`, but i want to bulk update the number in a specific colum `cost` by multipling with `0.826446281`

Is this possible? And how do i do that?
And it would be nice when the numbers are rounded bij 2 digigts. 
Like `3.39 * 0.826446281 = 2.80`

I have a screenshot of the column i want to update.
[image]
Who can help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET cost = cost * 0.826446281
```

Simple as that. Sure you want to update every row in the table? Not adding a `WHERE` clause?

It's always a good idea to first see which rows will get updated and how, like this:

```
SELECT cost * 826446281 /*and probably other columns*/
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. How can i round the numbers to 2 decimals automatically?

Comment: `ROUND(cost * 0.826446281, 2)`

Comment: hi, i do want to add a `where` in the sql like `WHERE attribute_id=73` How do i do that in the `UPDATE` query? I can get it in the `SELECT` query but not in the `UPDATE`

Comment: Of course you can, simply do `UPDATE your_table SET cost = cost * 0.826446281 WHERE attribute_id = 73;`